# How do I find out which exceptions std::map methods can throw?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I would like to handle exceptional circumstances when using std::map (C++) methods, as well as when using things like boost::unordered_map methods.  However, looking at method documentation (e.g.: insert) doesn't provide a list of exceptions that I can catch.

Comment: Read a better documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that's an excellent and very helpful selection. If you can point me to better documentation than what I get by searching Google that would be great!

Comment: @JorgePeach: cppreference.com is best online documentation.

Comment: I have already seen some of it (e.g.: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert). Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Comment: @JorgePeach: Get the final draft of C++11. The working drafts are free.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at *good* documentation: if you're not sure then - ultimately - the Standard, but e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert may be more convenient and has an Exceptions heading covering most variants (hopefully will be completed someday).  You're not likely to find better documentation for boost than that kept online at the boost site.

If a good reference doesn't document exceptions, it's usually because that function's code isn't explicitly written to throw any - though that doesn't mean there can't be exceptions thrown as the arguments to a function are prepared, as a side effect of memory allocation or some reasonable operation on objects e.g. copy construction or operators, or during the construction of a result.  All that's common sense though.

The Standard's explicit requirements re `std::map`...

> 23.2.4.1 Exception safety guarantees [associative.reqmts.except]
>
> 1 For associative containers, no clear() function throws an exception. erase(k) does not throw an exception
>   unless that exception is thrown by the container’s Compare object (if any).
>
> 2 For associative containers, if an exception is thrown by any operation from within an insert() function
>   inserting a single element, the insert() function has no effect.
>
> 3 For associative containers, no swap function throws an exception unless that exception is thrown by the
>   swap of the container’s Compare object (if any).

---

> 23.4.4.3 map element access [map.access]
>
> T& at(const key_type& x);
>
> const T& at(const key_type& x) const;
>
> 10 Throws: An exception object of type out_of_range if no such element is present.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I've already seen that documentation as well, but I didn't see a list of exceptions thrown or a categorical statement that the method doesn't throw any, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Aha! That's great, I'll be sure to refer to the standard in cases like these, thanks much! I kicked off my download of it after your first reply but hadn't looked back at it before you edited the reply.

Comment: Sure - no worries.  At least a draft Standard is a good thing to have around... am sure you'll find it useful often.

Answer (score 3):

Jorge,

Standard containers can only throw an `out-of-range` exception on access, they **do not throw exceptions** on other operations. However, the contained items can throw in an inner operation (constructor, assignation, comparison) when this operation is overloaded. That's why @tony-d link gives the best answer : this documents the behavior of the container when some underlying element raise during manipulations (insert/clear/swap).

The only exception left that can be raised are memory access violations and out-of-memory errors, which you should handle globally (and very carefully) at every high level, if at all.